# uib-dropdown outsideClick not working when used with is-open

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this template:

```
 <div class="col-xs-1 " ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="dropdown"
                     uib-dropdown
                     auto-close="outsideClick"
                     is-open="isOpen">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="">
                        <li ng-repeat="service in account.services">
                            <a href="#">
                                        <span>
                                           {{service.name}}
                                        </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to open `dropdown` when user both click on the `a` tag with class `drop-down` or also on the whole `div` (here is a rectangle), I tried to manually open dropdown by clicking on its containing `div` by using `ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen"` , it works fine by this approach but there is another problem that `dropdown` does not close when I click on any outside element, I used `auto-close=outsideClick` but it didn't helped.

any idea how to get it working?

Comment: you can even utilize 'for' attribute.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes of course, you can refer this url, in which you will see that, on click label, option button will be checked.:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label

Comment: @JigarPrajapati There is not for or input control here mate !

Comment: I tried to explain you by that scenario, like from which you can get the idea to get your thing done, that was not the exact result of your question.

Comment: Usually its not a good idea to put clickable elements (the `<a>` and the dropdown) inside a clickable container (the `<div>`)

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I replaced the `a` tag with a `div` but It didn't help, but thanks I'll consider your point.

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a stackoverflow working sample recreating the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is because of the event propagation. `uib-dropdown-toggle` directive will change the is-open flag and the on-click on the outer div is changing it back.

Please find the solution [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UBsVAhIgbD89WE3H35l1?p=preview)